# How to automatically print from Windows server to local printer

Tags: cloud, printing

I have a Windows desktop app that runs in EC2 and works perfectly for user-related things (using the app through remote desktop), including printing to local printers. However, the software has a feature that automatically prints PDFs for incoming requests, which works fine for local installations (non-EC2) since the printer is either USB or LAN, but I can't figure out how to have it print to a local printer when the remote desktop session is disconnected or logged out. I was about to use Google Cloud Print, which seems like it would work and is built into the firmware of a lot of printers, but it will be discontinued at the end of 2020. I see several alternatives listed here https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006 but they all seem to be designed for large organizations to enable printing for their numerous employees.

I'm looking for a recommendation from someone who has successfully implemented a a cloud printing technique/system that would allow a Windows program/app running on an EC2 instance to print to a local printer.

Comment: From the point of view of the Windows server instance, your printer is _remote_. The server has to have some way to connect to it.

Comment: Yep. That's why I asked the question here. "some way" is what I'm looking for.

Comment: `I see several alternatives listed... but they all seem to be designed for large organizations to enable printing for their numerous employees.` - What doess it matter who the intended audience is? If they solve your problem then why not use them?

Comment: @joeqwerty That is a good question and I may pursue them. They are more complicated than something like Google Cloud print, so I'm hoping to find something simpler to try first.

Comment: Additionally, I'm hopeful to find someone who has a specific recommendation, even if it is one of the listed alternatives. That would save me the time and trouble of evaluating each one, or at least allow me to prioritize the ones that someone can recommend.

Comment: If local printer has public IP (or supports DDNS), you can configure local TCP printer port on EC2 and use it as "local attached".